# unable to unstake or withdraw tokens

Tags: cpu, unstake

I tried to withdraw my EOS from Simpleos wallet but was getting " Error: billed CPU time (286 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (0 us).
So ,I decided to stake some more eos to enable the transaction. I have ended up (by accident),staking all of my eos (90% cpu and 10% net).
Now I am trying to unstake them and I am getting the same error.
I am not very tech at all and was only wanting to withdraw, can anyone offer a solution please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the anchor wallet or the free power up https://eospowerup.io/free https://greymass.com/en/anchor/

Comment: Similar situation here. I did not know withdrawal would become a nightmare.

Comment: It has taken too much of my time, and at most all I have there is just over $200 worth.  Am feeling like moving on and considering it a total loss.  It's already a huge loss at current market prices and it feels like I am adding to the loss with the time and anxiety.

Comment: @Kim, read the first commit here pls. The information is available, you just need to read and follow the answers posted and you will be able to unstake.